# laravel how to use auth:attempt without password (replace by other column)

Tags: laravel

I have column nik, password, and pin in users table, and I want to use auth::attempt with 2 case

1. if column pin is null then auth::attempt use parameter nik and password `Auth::attempt(['empnik' => $empnik, 'password' => "12345678"]);`
2. if column pin is not null then auth::attempt use parameter nik and pin (note: pin is encrypted by hash like password) `Auth::attempt(['empnik' => $empnik, 'pin' => "123456"]);`.

in second case the return is fail because maybe pin not check using hash like password, even though my pin is encrypted by hash. So how to `Auth::Attempt` validate column `pin` using hash? is it possible?

this my user model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'empnik','empname', 'email', 'password', 'pin'
    ];


    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'pin'
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the password used on the User.php model, with the following method.

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    if ($this->pin) {
        return $this->pin;
    }

    return $this->password;
}
```

Now that needs to be hashed and there is an not optimal easy approach or the correct version.

---

**The easy not optimal approach**

Simply hash it when you check it.

```
if ($this->pin) {
    return Hash::make($this->pin);
}
```

Or Update all the pins to be hashed and when saving or updating it use the hash function.

```
$user->pin = Hash::make($request->pin);
```